# HTTP Status 404 Error when Running Upload File Code

Tags: java, jsp, upload

I am getting the error "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" at the point where I click the Submit button.  The path given seems to be correct. Is there anything about this code that would cause that error to occur?

```
<form name="uploadForm" action="index.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <%
            String saveFile="";
            String contentType = request.getContentType();

            if((contentType != null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)){

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
                int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
                byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
                int byteRead = 0;
                int totalBytesRead = 0;

                while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
                    byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
                    totalBytesRead += byteRead;
                }

                String file = new String(dataBytes);
                saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
                saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
                saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
                int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
                String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
                int pos;
                pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
                pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
                pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
                pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
                int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
                int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
                int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

                File ff = new File("C:/Users/JBG/Desktop/SampleFile2.docx"+saveFile);

                try{
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
                    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();}catch(Exception e){out.println(e);}
            }
        %>

        <input type="file" name="file" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: HTTP code 404 means there is something wrong in the path of action .Code seems fine.

Comment: @Daron Please share full error/exception stacktrace.

Comment: The full error/exception stacktrace is as follows: SEVERE:   PWC6117: File "C:\Users\JBG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ReadFileProgram\build\web\index.jsp" not found

Comment: My index.jsp file is in the following location.   (C:\Users\JBG\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ReadFileProgram\web\WEB-INF\jsp\index.jsp)             What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are getting 404 error message. This error message indicate that

```
The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link; hence the 404 error is one of the most recognizable errors users can find on the web.[1]
```

So there is a little mistake while  file operations correct below line.

in your code

```
File ff = new File("C:/Users/JBG/Desktop/SampleFile2.docx"+saveFile);
```

Replace below syntax.

`File ff = new File("C:/Users/JBG/Desktop/directory_name/"+saveFile);`

OR

`File ff = new File("C:/Users/JBG/Desktop/"+saveFile);`

Comment: Which ide are you using to develop application?  also you are using wrong path to acess jsp file. If you are.using any IDE then please make sure your all jsp/html files should be in web pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

You action tag should point to a valid endpoint servlet /webservice . It looks like you are pointing it to a jsp file. That said, mixing presentation logic and server side logic was done in the early 2000s. Things have improved a lot over the past decade. My recommendation would be to look at Jersey + Twitter Bootstrap or even Play for implementing the stuff you are doing.